# Creating an array of size n within a function where n is an integer parameter of the function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Is there an effective or analogous way to perform this task in C++?

```
void function(int n) {
    int array[n] = {};
}
```

I'm trying to implement the merge sort algorithm in C++ and it's a little trickier than [its implementation in Java](http://pastebin.com/10TFNzJE). It essentially relies on the ability to declare an array in this manner.

Comment: That's only supported as a compiler extension. Correct way in c++ is to use a `std::vector<int> array(n);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not actually familiar with `std::vector<int>array(n);`.

Comment: Use C. C's got real variable length arrays, C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Alex I have put a link to the documentation in my answer

Comment: @Alex `I'm not actually familiar with std::vector<int>array(n);`  That's why you asked.

Comment: @cmaster Besides robbing OP of all the C++ features they might want to use, a VLA on the stack also isn't very useful for this specific application (merge sort), since one might want to sort arrays larger than a few MB.

Comment: @delnan Is it true that the `std::vector<int>array(n)` is the proper method in this case? I believe my merge sort method in java is proper, so I figure translating it 1:1 to C++ as best as I can would be effective.

Comment: @Alex Yes, use `std::vector`.  Also, C++ is *not* Java.  Just because Java looks like C++ doesn't mean you can write C++ as if it's Java.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Clearly. They're not so dissimilar though.

Comment: @Alex - They may not be dissimilar on the surface, but there are a whole lot of differences.  Don't fall into the trap of relying on Java or Java semantics when writing C++ code.  You'll wind up with buggy, if not "odd" looking code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll keep that in mind. Does what I've written [here](https://i.imgur.com/FhJnkPb.png) seem accurate? I'm trying to implement this, but as I said, I'm still a C++ novice.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax

```
int array[n] = {};
```

isn't supported as part of standard c++. There are compiler extensions though supporting array allocation on the stack.

The correct way doing this in c++ is

```
void function(int n) {
    std::vector<int> array(n);
}
```

See [**`std::vector<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) reference documentation for more info.

Comment: FYI: your first code sample is called an VLA (variable length array). It is supported in C (C11) but not in C++. This will create a dynamically size array on the stack. For something such a merge sort this will very likely overflow the stack.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is used for cases like this:

```
#include <vector>
// ...
void function(int n) {
    std::vector<int> array(n);
}
```

It allocates an array of size `n` for you, and automatically manages its memory.

Comment: I've heard that dynamic memory allocation has potentially problematic implications when concerning objects. I heard this specifically in reference to use of a string object versus a c-string, or char array. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: @Alex _"potentially problematic implications"_ Which ones in particular? Heap memory usage/fragmentation? Performance? Portability for small MCU's? Certainly nothing that would affect a simple merge sort implementation on a standard PC.

Comment: @Alex That's exactly why `std::vector` and `std::string` exist. They take care of all the memory handling details. Manually managed memory like C-strings and raw arrays is much more error prone.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As far as the use of strings vs. c-strings, I believe the issue raised was something along the lines of being able to store a string within an object on file. Does any of what I'm saying seem at all familiar? I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. I'm fairly new to C++ as a language still.

Comment: @Alex that doesn't make any sense, whoever you heard from probably doesn't know what they are talking about

Comment: @Alex There aren't any issues as long a proper serialization mechanism is used for data structures (such cannot be easily written to files as plain memory image copy of the structure).

Comment: @MattMcNabb My professor. I'm probably quoting him wrong, though. I don't quite understand the issues (assuming there are any) with using a string vs. a c-string in any case.

Comment: `vector` is the C++ equivalent of Java arrays. Java strings are weird but `std::string` is closer than C-style strings.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Out of curiosity, why are Java strings weird?

Comment: @zenith they're all non-modifiable

Answer (score -1):

Simple allocation is OK if you don't need the vector:

```
void function(int n) {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> array (new int[n]);

    // for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) array[i] = i;
}
```

std::unique_ptr will delete the array in the destructor (of course).